# Erro programa iniciante em C

Tags: c

Estou começando a programar agora e estou com um problema no exemplo abaixo. A questão pede para calcular o imposto de renda, de acordo com o salário recebido pela pessoa. O erro é que, independente do valor do salário que eu coloco como entrada, o programa imprimi "isento", até mesmo para valores que ultrapassando o intevalo relativo à isenção.

## include

```
int main (){
    double salario, aux1, aux2, aux3;

    printf("digite seu salario: ");
    scanf("%lf", &salario);

    if(salario>=0.00 || salario<=2000.00){
        printf("Isento");}
    else {if(salario>=2000.01 || salario<3000.00){
        aux1=salario*0.08;
        printf("O valor a ser pago e %.2lf", &aux1);}

    else {if(salario>=3000.01 || salario<=4500.00){
        aux2=salario*0.18;
        printf("o valor a ser pago e %.2lf", &aux2);}

    else {if(salario>=4500.01){
        aux3=salario*0.28;
        printf("O valor a ser pago e %.2lf", &aux3);}
            }
          }
        }


return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no identificador lógico || nesse caso você deveria usar o &&.

Na sua lógica você está dizendo que salario pode ser maior que 0 ou menor que 2000,  só que 2001 já é maior que 0 então o retorno é verdadeiro.

você usaria || se por exemplo necessitasse de uma expressão assim `x < 1000 || x > 2000`

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema está aqui:

```
if(salario>=0.00 || salario<=2000.00){
```

Qualquer valor atenderá a tal condição (todos os números positivos serão maiores ou iguais a zero bem como todos os negativos serão menores ou iguais a 2000)

Creio que o teste correto seja:

```
if(salario>=0.00 && salario<=2000.00){
```

O mesmo se aplica a todos os outros comandos if.

Comment: Nossa, realmente. Não tinha me atentado a isso. Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Além desse problema com operadores && e ||, existem outros problemas também.
Ao chamar o **printf** você esta passando o operador de endereçamento **&**, assim ele mostrara o endereço da variável em memoria e não seu valor.

```
Errado - printf("O valor a ser pago e %.2lf", &aux1);}
Correto - printf("O valor a ser pago e %.2lf", aux1);}
```

E uma dica para iniciante. Treine bastante a edentação do seu código.
Bons Estudo!

Answer (score 0):

Esta resposta é uma versão reformatada, porque o programa como foi postado está pessimamente formatado.

```
int main ()
{
  double salario, aux;

  printf("digite seu salario: ");
  scanf("%lf", &salario);

  if (salario >= 0.00 && salario <= 2000.00)
  {
    printf("Isento");
  }

  else if (salario >= 2000.01 && salario < 3000.00)
  {
    aux = salario * 0.08;
    printf("O valor a ser pago e %.2lf", aux);
  }

  else if (salario >= 3000.01 && salario <= 4500.00)
  {
    aux = salario * 0.18;
    printf("o valor a ser pago e %.2lf", aux);
  }

  else if (salario >= 4500.01)
  {
    aux = salario * 0.28;
    printf("O valor a ser pago e %.2lf", aux);
  }

  else
  {
    printf("salario digitado negativo!");
  }

  return 0;
}
```